# Styles/theme were not applying after upgrade to rails 7.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recently we had upgraded the Ruby on Rails app (Ruby 2.7.2 to 3.2,Rails 5.2 to 7.0.6). After upgraded the app theme styles were missing. Below is the Gem file

```
ruby '3.2.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3'


gem 'pg', '~> 1.5'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3'

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'rack-cors', '~> 1.0', require: 'rack/cors'
gem 'rpush', '~> 3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', '~> 1.8'
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
```

application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "devise_bootstrap_views";

@import "global";
@import "authform";
```

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

manifest.js

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts.js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets.css
```

Can any one help how can i fix it?

Comment: Rails 7 uses Bootstrap in a different way compared to the previous Rails versions and you also want to look into compatibility issues. I hope that this video for example, or a couple of similar ones could help you to get the answers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyqjecyCv3A